# Database record containing multiple entries in one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am working on a web app written in rails. It is currently running on heroku with a postgres database.

I am supposed to add a feature where users may enter **up to three** codes for each one of the user's students. The codes themselves are irrelevant, they are simply strings that will be entered into the database.

This brings me to my dilemma. I am unsure of how to best store the codes in terms of their relationship to the student table. My original thought was to use the rails method `serialize` to store up to three codes in an array, but I have read that more often than not, storing data in an array in a database is not what you want to do.

Should I create a new table "codes" and set up a `has_many` relationship with the "students" table? Or is there a more preferable away to set up this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your situation, this sounds like the most reasonable approach to have a `Code` model and then setup ***has_many*** association with `Student` model.

`student` ***has_many*** `codes` and
`code` ***belongs_to*** `student`.